# How may i use the thread in my program?

Tags: android, multithreading, shapedrawable

I want to move the image on screen using thread I have tried but its not working fine due to improper code of thread. I am able to get the image and i want to move the image on screen
In this code i want to move ovalshaped image and i dont want that it must effect the jerry image but the problem is thread is also implementing over it
The margenMaxX, margenxy are the maximum width and height

```
    public class AnimatedView extends ImageView {
            public AnimatedView(Context context) {
                super(context);

Resources res = context.getResources();
            drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.jerry);
        mDrawable =  new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
                mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(0xffffAC23);
    } 
     protected void onDraw(final Canvas cc) {
            final Context context = null;
drawable.setBounds(x , y , x + width, y + height);
            drawable.draw(cc);
            invalidate();
                Thread thread = new Thread()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        while(i<=margenMaxX && j<=margenmaxy) {
                                            sleep(100);
                                           // context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                            //handler.post(r);
                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                         @Override
                                         public void run() {
                                                 mDrawable.setBounds(i, j ,i+ width, i+ height);
                                                 mDrawable.draw(cc);

                                        }

                                    });
                                            //invalidate();
                                            i=i+10;
                                            j=j+10;
                                        }
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            thread.start();

            }
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want to draw in a new Thread?

Comment: UI handling must be done on a UI thread - the main thread.

Comment: I am developing a game so i want this work to be executed seprately

Answer (score 0):

You have to update UI within UI thread. Try this, its not tested but it should work

```
protected void onDraw(final Canvas cc) {
    Thread thread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            while(i<=margenMaxX && j<=margenmaxy) {
                                sleep(100);
                                //handler.post(r);
                               context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                     mDrawable.setBounds(i, j ,i+ width, i+ height);
                                     mDrawable.draw(cc);

                            }

                        });
                                //invalidate();
                                i=i+10;
                                j=j+10;
                            }
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();

}}
```

see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) for details

Comment: thanks but its giving error in line context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()    protected void onDraw(final Canvas cc) {
         final Context context = null;
             Thread thread = new Thread()
                         {
                             @Override
                             public void run() {
                                 try {
                                     while(i<=margenMaxX && j<=margenmaxy) {
                                         sleep(100);
                                         context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

Comment: Its saying add cast to context than i did this  ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  but its showing exception in this.....03-24 13:16:27.070: E/AndroidRuntime(10277):  at com.game2.MainActivity$AnimatedView$1.run(MainActivity.java:218)

Comment: @Abhi whats on line number 219 in MainActivity.java ?

Comment: thanks for your help the ball is moving over the screen but it is also making the another image to sleep and i want ball to move slowly i increased time but its not working